# How to slice a pandas dataframe by rows between two column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, slice

```
     A          B    C  D      E    
0  1.0 2013-01-02  1.0  1   test  
1  1.0 2014-01-02  1.0  2    car  
2  1.0 2015-01-02  1.0  3 tested  
3  1.0 2016-01-02  1.0  4  train
```

How do I slice a pandas dataframe to contain three consecutive rows out of the above based on the values in column E, e.g. from 'test' to 'tested'?

Comment: What do you think the answer is... show us what your expected outcome looks like.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use `pd.DataFrame.iloc`:

```
df.iloc[0:3]

     A           B    C  D       E
0  1.0  2013-01-02  1.0  1    test
1  1.0  2014-01-02  1.0  2     car
2  1.0  2015-01-02  1.0  3  tested
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not why I come up this solution , ugly but work ..

```
df.iloc[df.index[(df.E=='test').eq(1)].values[0]:df.index[(df.E=='tested').eq(1)].values[0]+1,:]

Out[151]: 
     A           B    C  D       E
0  1.0  2013-01-02  1.0  1    test
1  1.0  2014-01-02  1.0  2     car
2  1.0  2015-01-02  1.0  3  tested
```